# Фабрика объектов

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, javascript

Создается куча объектов. Как сделать, чтобы создаваемые объекты могли наследовать через prototype?

```
<script>
    function Red() {
        this.pl = 'polska';
        this.bel = 'belarus'
    }
    Red.prototype.country = function () {
        return this.bel
    }

    function Class(dz) {
        //Red.call(this);
        var obj = {};
        obj.value = dz; // свойство
        obj.some_method = function () { // метод
            console.log('some_method invoked');
        }
        return obj;
    }
    // Class.prototype=new Red;
    var obj1 = Class('c');
    var obj2 = Class('m');
    alert(obj1.pl + ':' + obj2.bel)
</script>
```

Comment: так что ли?

    var obj = {};
    obj.__proto__ = new Red();

если нет, подробнее опишите задачу

Comment: Да но для всех браузеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы закоментировали `Red.call(this);` пытаясь сделать нечто такое?

```
var obj = {};        
Red.apply(obj);
```

Но так нету доступа к прототипу, тогда почему не просто:

```
var obj = new Red();
```

Comment: Spectre все получилось.Спасибо